# ng-submit is not working when enter key is pressed from focused input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason, when I push enter after un-hiding my input, the `submit_form()` function does not get run. Does anyone have any ideas on why this wouldn't work?

```
<form name="theform" ng-submit="submit_form()" novalidate>

        <div ng-hide="show_form">
            <div ng-click="show_input()">Click me</div>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="show_form">
            <input type="text" class="md_input" ng-model="inputstuff" placeholder="name" required />   
        </div>

</form>
```

Inside controller:

```
$scope.show_form = false;
$scope.show_input = function() { $scope.show_form = true; }
$scope.submit_form = function() { console.log("TRIGGER"); }
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to have functional submit with and without focused input?

Comment: If you focus on the textbox and then press enter it will work

Comment: @wayneellery it doesn't work that's my issue! I think the hiding the doc may have something to do with it

Comment: @arman1991 nope just need it to work when I push enter when I'm focused in the input box

Comment: Interesting... By me is everything wokring as you described...

Comment: What browser and angular version are you using? It works in my [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Btow8Z5OlIzjaeVTQuzx?p=preview)

Comment: I think forms responds to enter input only if it contains a submit-type button, regardless you use angular or any JavaScript library.